# HTML readable separate script tag

Tags: javascript, html, file

The title is maybe a bit misleading. I need to work with huge files (The smallest one is 210 KB), so it isn't a very fast way to get them trough AJAX. I tried including them in a plain text script tag, and it worked, but these files are a couple of thousands lines, so they made the HTML code very very long. The IDE froze, when i tried to delete 3 at once. My question is basically:

Is there a way, to read a code in a separate file, where I could just do

```
<script src="myFile.ext" id="myFile"></script>
```

and it would work the same as having it in the main html tag?

Comment: @John it uses AJAX

Comment: Ajax is best way of doing it. Why do you think that `script` would work better than `Ajax` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to use the data in the file included with a script tag, unless it is javascript, and actually calls a function defined on your page.
Read about [`jsonp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Your best bet is to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only overhead to load with AJAX is the extra HTTP request headers, and that's negligible comparing to your huge file size. I don't understand why you think it's faster to load together with other HTML.